# R dplyr group by more than 2 variables and calculate relative percentages inside each 1st variable group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I would like to group a dataframe by 4 variables, summarise it with a count and then calculate the percentage of counts each row accounts for compared to the total counts in each group of the 1st variable. As a last step, i calculate a cumulative percentage and assign the row to a category based on certain thresholds.

A simple example first:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

test <- flights %>%
  left_join(airlines, by = c('carrier'), na_matches = "never") %>%
  group_by(origin, name) %>%
  summarise(count_flights = n()) %>%
  arrange(origin, desc(count_flights)) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(count_flights) * 100,
         cumprop = cumsum(prop),
         ABC = cut(cumprop, c(0,80,95,100), labels = c('A','B','C')))
```

This works fine, i get the number of flights per NYC airport and carrier, along with the percentage each row accounts for in relation to the airport total.

Now, this does not work when grouping by 2 more variables:

```
test2 <- flights %>%
  left_join(airlines, by = c('carrier'), na_matches = "never") %>%
  group_by(origin, name, dest, day) %>%
  summarise(count_flights = n()) %>%
  arrange(origin, desc(count_flights)) %>%
  mutate(prop = prop.table(count_flights) * 100,
         cumprop = cumsum(prop),
         ABC = cut(cumprop, c(0,80,95,100), labels = c('A','B','C')))
```

What i expect is the cumsum to equal 100 just before a change of airport/origin, or put another way, the percentage of each rows to be calculated against the total flights of each airport.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to `group_by` the variables that you want to use for the new, less specific bucket (origin), and then divide the count by the total count in a `mutate`:

```
flights %>%
  left_join(airlines, by = c('carrier'), na_matches = "never") %>%
  group_by(origin, name, dest, day) %>%
  summarise(count_flights = n()) %>%
  arrange(origin) %>%
  group_by(origin) %>%
  mutate(prop = count_flights/sum(count_flights),
         cumprop = cumsum(prop))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... but i think you meant to only group by origin in the second group_by didn't you? If i do so, that gives me the correct result...

Comment: yes -- had mistaken what the `name` column was referring to. edited